# understanding spring filters in Spring 3.2.8

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing a filter for security reasons.... The point that the page gets frozen and I don't know exactly why because the filter in fact is not still doing anything !

```
<!-- spring security csrf -->
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>fr.telecom.support.context.DevicesSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Here my filter:

```
public class DevicesSecurityFilter extends DelegatingFilterProxy {

    public DevicesSecurityFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DevicesSecurityFilter(Filter delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    public DevicesSecurityFilter(String targetBeanName) {
        super(targetBeanName);
    }

    public DevicesSecurityFilter(String targetBeanName,
            WebApplicationContext wac) {
        super(targetBeanName, wac);
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {


        System.out.println ("do Filter...");

        //super.doFilter(request, response, filterChain);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter **is** doing something: it prevents the request from going to the next filter/servlet in the chain, and doesn't send anything to the response. So it basically intercepts all requests and responds with a blank response to all of them.

For the filter to be "transparent", its `doFilter()` method must contain

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

or, since it's a DelegatingFilterProxy, it shouldn't have any doFilter() method at all, and instead let the parent's doFilter method implementation do its job: delegating to the Spring bean it's configured to use. In fact, you shouldn't even create subclasses of DelegatingFilterProxy: as its name indicates, it works, on its own, by *delegating* to a Spring bean. The Spring bean should be the one doing the filtering job.

By overriding the `doFilter()` method, you're preventing that delegation to happen.